# My laptop won't turn on and I don't know why

Tags: asus-laptop

A few weeks ago I kinda broke my laptop screen, so my brother bought a new screen. When he gave me the laptop it worked, windows was up and everything was working but when I left the computer for awhile and then came back, the screen was totally black.

I thought well okay, the laptop must have turned off or something. But when I pressed the power button nothing happend. I have tried for about 3 days now, I can't turn it on. I have read and tried everything but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Ensure that you have the electrical power connected to it and that the adapter is working to charge it. If the power adapter isn't charging it and the batter is dead, then obviously it won't turn on. Try taking out the battery, unplugging it from the power adapter, and hold down on the laptop power button for 10 seconds. Try with no battery and just electrical and see if it comes on now. Try with the batter and electrical and see if it comes on. . . Quick thoughts~

Comment: Take out the battery and press and hold the power button with the AC adaptor on.  It might just be Hibernating.  Since it's new, now's probably a good time to return it for a new one...

Comment: I assume that when you say 'It will not power on' that this means it does nothing at all. No LEDs flash, no fan spins up,...' Is that correct or does the system do something but the screen stays black ?

Comment: @Hennes Nothing happens at all. The system does not work...no LEDs flash or anything

Comment: since it seems like maybe it's related to the screen, have you tried opening it up and disconnecting the screen ribbon cable and turning it on without the screen? (you should be able to tell if it worked by the lights). Since the wifi antennas are located in the screen most of the time, it might be worth trying to take out the wifi card also just to see if that had anything happen

Comment: Have you tried charging the battery? When a battery has no charge left the laptop stops working.

Comment: No I have not, i will try soon though. Thank u for the tip. Hopefully it will work :)